# Rails 7 -- scope for associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scopes

There are answers for this, but *not for Rails 7* which I think added a better way to do this:

```
Answer model: `belongs to :question`
Question Model: `has_many :answers`
```

Then, in Question Model:

```
  scope :answered, -> { where.associated(:answers) } #1
  scope :unanswered, -> { includes(:answers).where(answers: {id: nil})} #2
```

I found the first one, where.associated(:answers). But I believe theres a better way to do the second one, that is analogous to the first one. But I can't find or get that to work.

Answer (score 1):

from [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html#method-i-missing) it looks as if the syntax is:

```rb
scope :unanswered, -> { where.missing(:answers) }
```